# Stop the `extent` argument in Turtle from changing direction of circle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am working on a homework assignment where the instructions are:

> Using Turtle graphics, implement function planets(), which will simulate the planetary motion of Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars during one rotation of planet Mars. You can assume that:
>
> 1. At the beginning of the simulation, all planets are lined up (say along the negative y-axis).
> 2. The distances of Mercury, Venus, Earth, and Mars from the Sun (the center of rotation) are 58, 108, 150, and 228 pixels.
> 3. For every 1 degree circular motion of Mars, Earth, Venus, and Mercury will move 2, 3, and 7.5 degrees, respectively.
>
> The figure below shows the state of the simulation when Earth is about a quarter of the way around the Sun. Note that Mercury has almost completed its first rotation.
>
> [image: Expected image]

The output I am getting is:

[image: Actual image]

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
import math


s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()

def jump(t,x,y):
    'makes turtle t jump to coordinates (x,y)'
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()

def planets(t):

    #mercury
    jump(t,0,-58)
    t.circle(58,337.5)

    #venus
    jump(t,0,-108)
    t.circle(108,135)

#   earth
    jump(t,0,-150)
    t.circle(150,90)

#   mars
    jump(t,0,-228)
    t.circle(228,45)



planets(t)
turtle.done()
```

So basically, the direction is changing. How do I get the desired output? How do I stop the `extent` argument from changing the direction of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `extent` argument of `circle()` but rather you start each new orbit with the turtle in whatever arbitrary orientation it was in when it completed the previous orbit.  You need to set the turtle to a known orientation before drawing each orbit:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def jump(t, x, y):
    ''' makes turtle t jump to coordinates (x, y) '''

    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()

def planets(t):

    # mercury
    t.setheading(0)
    jump(t, 0, -58)
    t.circle(58, 337.5)
    t.stamp()

    # venus
    t.setheading(0)
    jump(t, 0, -108)
    t.circle(108, 135)
    t.stamp()

    # earth
    t.setheading(0)
    jump(t, 0, -150)
    t.circle(150, 90)
    t.stamp()

    # mars
    t.setheading(0)
    jump(t, 0, -228)
    t.circle(228, 45)
    t.stamp()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(0.5)
turtle.hideturtle()

planets(turtle)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]